# How to check a Thinkpad's specs? Such as 3G support and other things?

Tags: thinkpad, 3g

This is my computer, a Thinkpad x220. I am selling it because I need Xcode for iOS development. My plan is to get Macbook Air and then virtualize the Debian to it.

**How can I find the specs about the Thinkpad I am selling?** Does it have 3G -support? It has the IMEI -number at the bottom so my friend said that my laptop may have 3G support.

[image]

Comment: You should probably delete the pictures with your serial number, or blur it out... just fyi. The part number is public information and not sensitive, but the serial number is basically personally identifiable information, as it is unique to THAT laptop unit.

Comment: @allquixotic I cannot understand why I should blur it, what does it matter?

Comment: Your serial number and sometimes your name is all that is needed to perform account or warranty related services by calling Lenovo's tech support line. They don't ask for any more advanced forms of owner identification. If we knew your full name or even your last name, we could probably convince Lenovo to take out an RMA on your unit, or similar. ;P

Comment: @allquixotic thank you, I contacted Lenovo for assistance. What do you mean "to take out an RMA on your unit"? My friend said that I should not share the IMEI number because telephone-something could kill the unit off-site somehow. If there is any truth here, I could kill many-many machines because I know all names and I have local contact to most of them all the time but I find this very odd policy if it is true.

Comment: @allquixotic Any idea how other manufacturers act, perhaps I need to think twice which computer to buy next :)

Comment: @hhh How come you don't know the specs and that the machine has a SIM card in it? The SIM card isn't there when the machine is sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

1. The [Hardware Maintenance Manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/0a60739.pdf) for the X220
2. The [Parts Lookup](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/partsLookup.page) page
3. Your serial number and part number (graciously provided by your screenshots)

Doing the hard work for you, you have:

```
-   0000000000000000000000000000000102000586    Intel T4200 2.0G 1M R-0 PGA CPU 900477  Yes
0A59804 04T3598 FAP Dasher-Comet DVD Win7PROx64 SP1 US  Yes
0B41322 -   -   Yes
0B41341 04W3286 FRU Systemboard AMT/TPM/AES i5-2520MNV  Yes
0B42385 04W3767 FRU Ericsson F5521gw WWAN Module Japan S    Yes
41R0642 55Y3717 4GB PC3-10600 DDR3-1333 LOW-HALOGEN SODI    Yes
42T1203 -   -   Yes
42T1365 -   -   Yes
42T4862 -   -   Yes
42T5114 -   -   Yes
42X4525 -   -   Yes
45N0119 -   -   Yes
45N2132 -   -   Yes
60Y3252 -   -   Yes
60Y3270 -   -   Yes
71Y3514 -   -   Yes
93P5670 -   -   Yes
```

The `Ericsson F5521gw WWAN Module Japan S` is FRU `04W3767`

A quick google on the FRU shows for example [this](http://www.mini-laptop-accessories.com/lenovo-60y3279-04w3767-gogi3000-21mbps-mini-card-p-16535.html) which provides the details on the part. Normally you could find it in the HMM too but this one isn't showing up there.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this computer has 3G when some sim-card inserted? Found this about the 04W3767 [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Ericsson-IBM-Lenovo-F5521GW-Gobi3000-60Y3255-60Y3279-04W3767-3G-WWAN-Card-GPS-/140814699291).

Comment: Yes, it needs a SIM card and a supported carrier.

Comment: Found the sim-card -slot, under battery?! Picture [here](http://blackmoore.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/).

Comment: http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-77497